# cannot search wikipedia page with dbpedia using sparql

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, virtuoso

I am trying to make a SPARQL query in DBpedia on the Wikipedia pages but, queries such as `Random_forest` are available pages in Wikipedia but are not showing properly during the search query.

```
    SELECT ?d WHERE
{{
?a rdfs:label "Random_forest"@en.
?a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects> ?b.
?b rdfs:label ?c FILTER (lang(?c)="en").
?d <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?e.
?e rdfs:label ?c.
   }
      UNION
  {
?e <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?d.
?e rdfs:label "Random_forest"@en.
   }
}
```

The output is:

```
{ "head": { "link": [], "vars": ["d"] },
  "results": { "distinct": false, "ordered": true, "bindings": [ ] } }
```

Comment: what is the purpose of your query? I don't get the first `UNION` part. The random forest resource redirects to something which belongs to some category is what you're currently doing.

Comment: by the way, it doesn't work in general because the label is `"Random forest"@en"`, i.e. no underscore `_` char - labels are supposed to be the human readable form, you only need this for URIs - you would have easily seen this if you would look at the DBpedia page. `select * {?a rdfs:label "Random forest"@en. }`. And the resource `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Random_forest` redirects to nothing, so your result for the first `UNION` part will be empty anyways, just for the second part it will return the 3 `dct:subjects` related categories

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following where OPTIONALS cater to the fact that labels may not always exist in language tagged form in regards to solution production:

```
SELECT distinct ?d 
WHERE
{
    {
        OPTIONAL {?a rdfs:label "Random_forest"@en.}
        ?a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects> ?b.
        ?b rdfs:label ?c FILTER (lang(?c)="en").
        ?d <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?e.
        OPTIONAL {?e rdfs:label ?c.}
   }
      UNION
  {
        ?e <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?d.
        OPTIONAL {?e rdfs:label "Random_forest"@en.}
   }
}
```

[Live Results Page](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20distinct%20%3Fd%20WHERE%0D%0A%7B%7B%0D%0Aoptional%20%7B%3Fa%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Random_forest%22%40en.%7D%0D%0A%3Fa%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FwikiPageRedirects%3E%20%3Fb.%0D%0A%3Fb%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fc%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3Fc%29%3D%22en%22%29.%0D%0A%3Fd%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fsubject%3E%20%3Fe.%0D%0Aoptional%20%7B%3Fe%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fc.%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fe%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fsubject%3E%20%3Fd.%0D%0Aoptional%20%7B%3Fe%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Random_forest%22%40en.%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20) (DBpedia Snapshot Edition) .

[Live Results Page](http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+distinct+%3Fd+WHERE%0D%0A%7B%7B%0D%0Aoptional+%7B%3Fa+rdfs%3Alabel+%22Random_forest%22%40en.%7D%0D%0A%3Fa+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2FwikiPageRedirects%3E+%3Fb.%0D%0A%3Fb+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Fc+FILTER+%28lang%28%3Fc%29%3D%22en%22%29.%0D%0A%3Fd+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fsubject%3E+%3Fe.%0D%0Aoptional+%7B%3Fe+rdfs%3Alabel+%3Fc.%7D%0D%0A+++%7D%0D%0A++++++UNION%0D%0A++%7B%0D%0A%3Fe+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fsubject%3E+%3Fd.%0D%0Aoptional+%7B%3Fe+rdfs%3Alabel+%22Random_forest%22%40en.%7D%0D%0A+++%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&signal_void=on&signal_unconnected=on&run=+Run+Query+) (DBpedia Live Edition) .